# Regex within a Contains

Tags: c#, regex, string, contains

I am working in c# and i am trying to check a string for a value `{some value}`. Most importantly i am looking for whether the string contains {}, with something in between. I was thinking reg-ex but i don't really know how to implement that within a String.Contains. I have tried creating a reg-ex instance and passing that into the Contains but that doesnt seem to work. Please let me know if there is an easier approach.

```
if (uri.Contains("{one word}"))
    {

    }
return false;
```

This is what ive tried,

```
public bool SimpleResponseCodeCheck(string callTested, string testName) 
{
    testParams = SupportingMethodsClass.ReturnXMLData(callTested, testName);
    string uri;
    string method;
    string requestBody;
    string expResponseCode;
    string actResponseCode;
    string statusMessage;
    string respBody;
    Regex testParameter = new Regex("\\{.+\\}");

    testParams.TryGetValue("uri", out uri);
    testParams.TryGetValue("method", out method);
    testParams.TryGetValue("expResponseCode", out expResponseCode);
    testParams.TryGetValue("requestBody", out requestBody);

    if (testParameter.IsMatch(uri, 0))
    {

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why would you even try passing a Regex to `Contains`? Do you not have access to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: The right documentation to look at is the docs for the `Regex` class.

Comment: @SLaks: I meant that the OP knows about `Contains`, and that a glance at the documentation for that method would have shown that it has no regular expression functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `Regex.IsMatch()` function, which does exactly that.

Comment: .IsMatch is exactly what i was looking for thanks, as mentioned below i used the RegEx expression "\\{.+\\}"

Comment: @hfrog713: In the future, if you see a class and can't figure out how to use it, **read the documentation**!  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex

Comment: Ok i appreciate the advice, i guess what i was looking for help on was more the regular expression that i would use. Does mine appear correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a `Regex` object with a pattern, you can use the `Match()` method on the object to check if it matches the pattern. With the `Match` result object, you can check the `Success` property to see if it matched or not.

Additionally, it may be useful to extract the word inside of the `{...}` bit, which can be easily done with named capture groups.

Here's a simple example:

```
        var stringA = "This contains a {parameter} somewhere!";
        var stringB = "This contains an {argument} instead.";
        var stringC = "No parameters or arguments here!";

        var simpleRegex = new Regex(@"{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+}");
        var groupRegex = new Regex(@"{(?<Parameter>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)}");

        var simpleMatchA = simpleRegex.Match(stringA);
        var simpleMatchB = simpleRegex.Match(stringB);
        var simpleMatchC = simpleRegex.Match(stringC);

        var groupMatchA = groupRegex.Match(stringA);
        var groupMatchB = groupRegex.Match(stringB);
        var groupMatchC = groupRegex.Match(stringC);

        Console.WriteLine("String A: {0}", stringA);
        Console.WriteLine("String B: {0}", stringB);
        Console.WriteLine("String C: {0}", stringC);

        Console.WriteLine("Does A match? {0}", simpleMatchA.Success);
        Console.WriteLine("Does B match? {0}", simpleMatchB.Success);
        Console.WriteLine("Does C match? {0}", simpleMatchC.Success);

        Console.WriteLine("A value: {0}", groupMatchA.Groups["Parameter"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("B value: {0}", groupMatchB.Groups["Parameter"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("C value: {0}", groupMatchC.Groups["Parameter"].Value);
```

Here's the output:

```
String A: This contains a {parameter} somewhere!
String B: This contains an {argument} instead.
String C: No parameters or arguments here!
Does A match? True
Does B match? True
Does C match? False
A value: parameter
B value: argument
C value:
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer, gave me more information than i needed but that is never a bad thing. I ended up just using the .IsMatch method on a Regex class

testParameter = new Regex("\\{.+\\}");

this seems to work aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could try this:

```
Regex.Match(targetString, @"({)%s(})");
```